# Maven Spring fileUpload using uploadTempDir property

Tags: spring, file-upload

Actually my requirement is to store uploaded files in the classpath directory i.e. `src/main/resources/uploads`. (I am using maven project)

But the dispatcher is not able to find this path. I am getting the following error.

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multipartResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'uploadTempDir' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [uploads] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

**The below configuration is added in the dispatcher file:**

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1048576"/>
    <property name="uploadTempDir" ref="uploadDirResource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="uploadDirResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>/uploads</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The path `src/main/resources(/uploads)` is a path used by Maven BEFORE compiling. Your Server does not know anything about this path!

The artefacts in `src/main/resources(/uploads)` are copied within the war file into the directory `WEB-INF/classes/uploads`.

But this directory also contain the java class fiels, and you should never allow a user to modify or add files to that directory!

*One point that is may not correct with you configration is the whitespace in*

`<value>/uploads </value>`

Comment: Now /uploads is taken by the dispatcher servlet.The problem was I didnt add the uploads folder in the webContent. But still the files are not stored in the uploads folder. In the controller just i had given filename in the outputstream but still it is stored in the eclipse path. Anyone can suggest the solution for this?

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear enough in my answer: the whole construct is wrong. Use an "external" upload folder!